# Using an external email service to forward mails from WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I run a reasonably popular blog on WordPress and have  a fair number of comments forwarded to me by the mail server currently sitting on my web server.  However, I am in the process of moving to a new server where I do not want to run a mail server. For all my other site needs - user registration - I am doing this by forwarding all emails sent out by the system to a transactional mail service that handles email forwarding a whole lot better than my local mail server can.

I need to modify the WP code that alerts me by email each time there is a new comment on a post.  I assume that this is being done via [PHP's mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function or the like. I tried grep'ing all the *.php files on my WP blog for this but found little.

I am a competent PHP programmer so hacking the relevant WP PHP code to redirect all mails via my chosen transactional email provider holds little challenges for me.  However, I would be most grateful to anyone who might be able to tell me just where WP does its email sending - perhaps it does not use the PHP mail function as I have been assuming.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer to my own question.

After some more research I have eventually found [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail#Source_File).  As explained there WP sends its email via the *wp_mail* function which is located [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.3/src/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L0).

I hope that this answer will help anyone else who wants to replace local mail server based email handling with forwards to an external mail/transactional mail service.

Comment: Downvoted the answer because StackOverflow answers should be self-contained.  Please provide at least some keywords, file names, function names, and/or line numbers so that we can at least try to reconstruct something when inevitably your links die.